# How to set display scaling to 200% for i3 desktop environment

Tags: i3-wm

I am new to the i3 desktop environment. How do I set the display scaling to 200%?

Comment: Possible:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267885/how-do-i-scale-i3-window-manager-for-my-hidpi-display

Answer (score 2):

Edit the ~/.Xresources file with this:

```
Xft.dpi: 192

! These might also be useful depending on your monitor and personal preference:
Xft.autohint: 0
Xft.lcdfilter:  lcddefault
Xft.hintstyle:  hintfull
Xft.hinting: 1
Xft.antialias: 1
Xft.rgba: rgb
```

Then in the ~/.xinitrc file, append `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources`.

Source : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#X_Resources